# ColdFusion cfreport displaying DB data without a specified query

Tags: coldfusion, cfreport

Is there a way to associate a query to a `.cfr` report other than specifying it with the `query` *attribute* of the `cfreport` *tag*, or imbedding it directly using Query Builder?

I have a report that consist's of three sub-reports. The report is declared in a `cfm` file like so

```
<cfreport template="report.cfr" format="pdf" filename="report.pdf" overwrite="yes">
```

The Query Builder query is blank.

I cannot find where this report is wired to not only a single query, but the three that it requires to run. One of the queries is defined within the declaring `cfm`, it's just never set. There are also three separate `cfm`'s for printing each sub-report individually, and each of these separate files do have a query definition and are set using the `query` *attribute*. It's a very strange situation that I'm currently chalking up to a "caching issue".

Comment: The queries were defined in their respective reports. I didn't realize an RDS server needed to be configured, and wasn't even prompted with an error complaining about a broken reference to one (like how my boss was on his machine) so never pursued.

Comment: Can you provide example of your code? have you tried using store-procedure with multiple result-set instead of single query?

Comment: ... To clarify on my previous comment, if there is a query defined within the report file itself under the SQL Query Builder query mode, then it will not appear until a valid RDS server is properly added and pointed to (so I'm assuming the actual query in this mode is stored on the RDS server, unless the interface hides it for another reason, I'm not sure).

Comment: @Click This was more of a GUI tool configuration issue than a coding issue, and I just don't have time for screen shots, plus it's resolved.